# Getting wrong lat/lang after transforming from "EPSG:900913" projection to "EPSG:4326"

Tags: openlayers

In OpenLayer3 Map I'm getting lat/lang from nominatim and the map is in "EPSG:900913" projection and then transforming it to "EPSG:4326" projection .

if lat = 12.9791198 and lang = 77.5912997 then i am transforming like this,

```
var point = new ol.geom.Point([lan,lat]);
point.transform("EPSG:4326","EPSG:900913");
```

After transformation lat/lang should be [8643375.747091185,1460888.081802196] but i am getting [8637423.97259228,-13864431.524951909].

Comment: have you tried the "official" code EPSG:3857 ? Also note that you source and destination are unclear;  Your example is FROM WGS84 TO mercator, but your text and your point.transform are FROM mercator TO WGS84. Could you please edit your post to clarify ?

Comment: I am getting different right coordinates `gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:3857
77.5912997 12.9791198
8637423.97259228 1457346.85837884`

Comment: @radouxju  i have edited.

Comment: @radouxju its not working with    point.transform("EPSG:4326","EPSG:3857")

Comment: Are you sure the coordinates you're expected are good? because point.transform("EPSG:4326","EPSG:3857")  give the same as `gdaltransform` does.  So the problem can be how did you get your lat/lon values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating the point instance

```
var point = new ol.geom.Point([lon,lat]);
```

lon and lat value should be in numeric format previously they were in string format hence it was converting into wrong lat and long.